# Floating <li> with different heights

Tags: css, css-float

Is there any way how to make all list items of the same height? I searched this website and found this solution but it doesn't work for me if I add `float:left`. I need `float:left` for line breaks after each 4 images.

```
        ul.Gallery{display:table-row;}
        ul.Gallery li{float:left;list-style:none;margin:0 5px 5px 0;
    display:table-cell;background:red;}
```

```html
    <ul class="Gallery">
    <li><img src="image1.jpg"><p>description1</p></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg"><p>description2</p></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg"><p>description3</p></li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg"><p>description4 description4 description4 description4 description4 description4</p></li>
<li><img src="image5.jpg"><p>description5</p></li>

    </ul>
```

This is what I need:

[image]

and this is what I get if some images don't have any description or description length is different.:[image]

I can not set `width` or `min-heigth` for `<li>` elements because not all the images have description and description length may be very different.

I don't want to use javascript for this purpose.

Comment: JSfiddle please but `display: table-cell`will probably work for you.

Comment: I already use table-cell

Comment: You will not be able to realize your layout using this mark-up.  You need to wrap each 4-image group in a table-row element to take advantage of the common-height feature of table cells.  The alernative is to use JavaScript/jQuery.  You painted yourself into a corner...

Comment: Barring `flex-box` ....what he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (edited code a bit):

```
ul.Gallery{display:block; padding:0; margin:0;}
ul.Gallery li{
padding:0;
background:red;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width:23%;
margin:0 1% 5px 0;}
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uR9YV/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` and add `height:100%`

```
ul.Gallery li{
      list-style:none;
      margin:0 5px 5px 0;
      background:red;
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hazucahu/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change `float:left` for `display:table-cell` an the li/cells will all have the same height.

Note however, that you may have to restrict the width of the `li` as the text will cause different widths depending on it's length.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/5UgJ8/)

**CSS**

```
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    display: table;
}

li {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding:5px;
    width:20%;
}

li img {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;

}

li p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I need line breaks after each 4 images. If I remove float-left, all images are in 1 line.

Comment: You might want to add that to your question instead of **leaving out essential information.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of realizing this layout using rather different mark-up.

The feature of this layout is that the `li` elements all have the same height which
means that the red backgorund has the same height with a row.

If it were not for the red background color, this problem would be a lot easier to
solve.

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="GalleryWrap">
<ul class="Gallery">
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat is wearing a fur coat.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="Gallery">
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" />
        <p>The cat in the hat.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat is wearing a fur coat.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/100" />
        <p>The cat in the hat.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
.GalleryWrap {
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
ul.Gallery {
    display: table-row;
}
ul.Gallery li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid white;
}
ul.Gallery li img {
    width: 100%;
}
ul.Gallery li p {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Create a the CSS table `.GalleryWrap`, and use `display: table-row` for `ul.Gallery`.

Within each `ul.Gallery`, put in the four images, and repeat for each group of four.

I added a white border to control the spacing between cells, but you can also use
cell spacing and cell padding.

In practice, the mark-up could be generated automatically using a scripting language
like PHP or the features of the template system used to build the pages of the website.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DBZdf/

Note: This layout may be easier to build using flex, but flex is still rather new and supported only by the latest browsers.